# How to fix memory leak in Python sqlite3?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, sqlite

I have a query which I want to execute in multiple .sqlite files with sqlite3. The problem is when conn.close() executes the memory used to run the previous .sqlite file is not cleared if I save some of the results.

To explore the problem I ran memory_profile:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
29   19.324 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
30                             def my_func():
35   19.543 MiB    0.219 MiB       conn = sql.connect(db_file1)
36   22.293 MiB    2.750 MiB       for row in conn.execute(query):
37   22.293 MiB    0.000 MiB           print row
38   19.953 MiB   -2.340 MiB       conn.close()
39                             
40   19.953 MiB    0.000 MiB       conn = sql.connect(db_file2)
41   22.293 MiB    2.340 MiB       for row in conn.execute(query):
42   22.293 MiB    0.000 MiB           print row
43   19.953 MiB   -2.340 MiB       conn.close()
```

If I don't do anything with the data, just print it, when conn.close() runs 2.3 MiB is released.

Now suppose I do something with the data (e.g save what I need in a object)

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
29   19.336 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
30                             def my_func():
31   19.336 MiB    0.000 MiB       results = []                            
35   19.551 MiB    0.215 MiB       conn = sql.connect(db_file1)
36   34.879 MiB   15.328 MiB       for row in conn.execute(query):
37   34.879 MiB    0.000 MiB           d = Data()
38   34.879 MiB    0.000 MiB           d.i1, d.i2, d.i3, d.i4 = row[:4]
39   34.879 MiB    0.000 MiB           results.append(d)
40   34.879 MiB    0.000 MiB       conn.close()
41                             
42   34.879 MiB    0.000 MiB       conn = sql.connect(db_file2)
43   46.277 MiB   11.398 MiB       for row in conn.execute(query):
44   46.277 MiB    0.000 MiB           d = Data()
45   46.277 MiB    0.000 MiB           d.i1, d.i2, d.i3, d.i4 = row[:4]
46   46.277 MiB    0.000 MiB           results.append(d)
47   46.277 MiB    0.000 MiB       conn.close()
```

When conn.close() runs nothing is released, all the memory allocated during the running of the query is kept. I know that the increase in memory has in part to do with the fact that I'm saving the results, but I should see a decrease when conn.close() executes.
Any ideas why this is happening, or what I could do?

For reference Data has the following declaration

```
class Data:
  pass
```

EDIT

I also calculated the size of the results with the below function and it's 11.45 MB, so something else is holding 14 MB

```
def calc_memory(results):
  mem = 0    
  for res in results:
      mem += sys.getsizeof(res)
      mem += sys.getsizeof(res.i1)
      mem += sys.getsizeof(res.i2)
      mem += sys.getsizeof(res.i3)
      mem += sys.getsizeof(res.i4)
  mem += sys.getsizeof(results)
 return mem
```

Comment: Where are you `close`ing the cursors?

Comment: I'm not using a cursor, just the connection.execute(sql [, optional parameters]) function

Comment: And what is returned by `execute`?

Comment: <type 'sqlite3.Connection'> . The way I understand it sqlite3 creates a temporary cursor when you use the execute statement on a connection. By the way, I tried right now the same thing with a cursor and I get the same memory behavior